# Node.js issue :: Angular is not defined :: cannot fined bower packages :: nodegyp vs Python

Tags: python, angularjs, node.js, bower, jhipster

**Issue:**
after generating and starting my new jHipster API in the browser I got the following issue:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined*

**Before** the generation I installed the latest:

- node.js
- yo
- bower
- grunt-cli 
  according to the [guidelines](https://jhipster.github.io/installation.html)

**During** the generation I got the following warning and errors:

> I'm all done. Running npm install & bower install for you to install
>   the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command
>   yourself.
>
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install
>   K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\node_modules\bufferutil
>   node-gyp rebuild
>   K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\node_modules\bufferutil>if
>   not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
>   "C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild ) else (node rebuild ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack
>   Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON
>   env variable. gyp ERR! stack at failNoPython
>   (C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
>   gyp ERR! stack at
>   C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
>   gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) gyp ERR! System
>   Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\node_modules\bufferutil
>   gyp ERR! node -v v5.3.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1 gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: node-gyp
>   rebuild npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1
>
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install
>   K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\node_modules\utf-8-validate
>   node-gyp rebuild
>   K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
>   "C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild ) else (node rebuild ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack
>   Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON
>   env variable. gyp ERR! stack at failNoPython
>   (C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
>   gyp ERR! stack at
>   C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
>   gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) gyp ERR! System
>   Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\korban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\node_modules\utf-8-validate
>   gyp ERR! node -v v5.3.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1 gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install:
>   node-gyp rebuild npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
>   npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating
>   system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.6 bower angular-aria#1.4.8 ENOGIT
>   git is not installed or not in the PATH Running "ngconstant:dev"
>   (ngconstant) task Creating module aicwebadminapiApp at
>   src/main/webapp/scripts/app/app.constants.js...OK
>
> Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task Warning: Error: Cannot find where
>   you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I made long **investigations** about the:

- node_gyp vs Python issue
- "cannot find bower packages' issue
- "angular is not defined" issue

but I didn't find a working solution.

**Note:** mvn clean install and mvn spring-boot:run are running successfully!

If you have any useful thoughts to share about this I would really appreaciate it!

Thank you for your help in advance!

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

**Final solution**

**Fix for node_gyp vs Python issue:**

- Downgrade to: Node.js 4.2.3 LTS and npm 2.14.7,
- install [Python 2.7.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/) and Visual Studio Express (*www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44914*) as well 
  (see node-gyp dependencies:*github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation*)

**Fix for "cannot find bower packages' issue and "angular is not defined" issue:**

*Note:* First of all use rff-doctor(*github.com/rakuten-frontend/rff-doctor*) to verify system configuration for using Yeoman, Grunt and Bower etc. It will show you what is missing and how can you purchase it/them.

What was missing in my case:

- installing Git(*git-scm.com/downloads*) and setting it for using https instead of git with the following command: `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`
- installing Ruby(*www.ruby-lang.org/*) and adding it to the PATH
- installing Sass using gem: `gem install sass` and addig it to the PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few advices for setting up your NodeJS environment on Windows:

- don't install last NodeJS release, rather install the latest LTS release (Long Term Support)
- don't use npm 3 yet
- don't use deep project folder path (like "K:\work\HP_AIC_WebAdmin_Customization\workspace\aicwebadminapi\") as npm may hit Windows maximum path length for your node_modules content.
- install Python 2.x not 3.x

Consider using [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) or another nvm-like tool to install node.

You must also solve the git error, bower needs git for some modules not found in npm registry. You must fix your environment by installing git and making sure that the 'git' command is available in your path before retrying 'bower install command'. Some git is correctly installed but cannot work because it is blocked by a corporate firewall.

You could also try to run a diagnostic tool like [rff-doctor](https://github.com/rakuten-frontend/rff-doctor) to test your environment for git, grunt, bower and node. Don't follow its recommendation about Ruby and SASS as JHipster does not require them (it uses libsass through grunt/gulp).

Comment: Thank you for your advices Gaël! It solved one of the issues but not all of them unfortunately. 
/* Details in the original question under UPDATE. */
I'm considering the nodist, I will make a try with it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Nodist may not help here for this particular issue, it would help you for better managing your environement but as you alreadsy re-installed it it's a bit late.

Comment: You must solve the git issue, bower needs git for some modules not found in npm regsitry. You must fix the git issue by installing and making sure that the git command is available in your path before re(rying 'bower install command'.

Comment: Gaël, this rff-doctor is awesome! I had to install and set some more things: Ruby, Sass etc. Now it is working, I will summarize all of the steps at the bottom of my question soon!

Comment: Well you did not need to install Ruby and SASS because JHipster uses libsass which is written in C and is used by grunt or gulp. I pointed you to rff-doctor because I thought that your issue was around git that is tested by this tool. I updated my advice for further readers.

Comment: Actually without Ruby and Sass installation the bower and angular issues still existed so that is why I installed them.

Comment: Really surprised about that, which version of jhipster did you use?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! 2.26.1 (that was the latest in that time)